# retrieve value of data attribute from child selector

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where I am dynamically creating the following elements within a div with class 'contact-row':

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 edit-contact">
        <span data-ID="' + obj.ID + '">' + obj.Text + '</span>
        &nbsp;&#8211&nbsp;<span>' + obj.Notes + '</span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an on("click") for the element in which I would like to get the contents of the data attribute of the first span. I am trying this:

```
$(".contact-row").on("click", ".edit-contact", function () 
    var $t = $(this);
    var ID = $t.children("span:has[data-ID]").attr('data-ID');
    alert(ID);
});
```

The click works but the alerted out ID is 'undefined'. Is there a better way to make reference to this span's attribute?

Comment: I don't see any element with class `.contact-row` within your markup

Comment: $t.find("span:first-child").attr('data-ID'); ?

Comment: I edited to add clarification: the dynamically crated content is appended to a div with class 'contact-row'. My current assumption is that $(this) is not the containing <div class="col-md-12 edit-contact"> as intended

Comment: Try it with lowercase `data-id'.  I've noticed sometimes that the caps get lost in the html but the javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: To retrieve data attributes in jQuery, you can actually just use `$(element).data("id")` instead of `attr("data-id")`. While there seem to be other factors/issues at play, just a note moving forward.

Comment: @DanWier as RomanPerekhrest said, there's not div with class contact-row, and if you add as row your data, than you would use another function, because children is only 1 level search I think, so please provide your full html that can be tested

Comment: hmm, doesn't children return an array, you'd have to use each to iterate over them first right?

Comment: @Marko Mackic you're right it's only one level, he'd have to use find to go lower

Comment: @alexr101 yeah it does, but since it's only a single instance in edit contact you don't need iteration :) \

Comment: Just use `find` rather than `children`, and `"span[data-ID]"` instead of `"span:has[data-ID]"` for your selector. See [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) in the documentation

Comment: The argument to `:has` goes in parentheses, e.g. `:has([data-ID])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ID = $t.find("span:first-child").attr('data-id');
```

with a lower case id did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

For checking if element has attribute you can simply use `element[attrib]`, and I supposed you're using some div level higher wher you put rows with your contacts, but if that's not the case you can use just your selector except `contact_rows` because `find` will find children elements at any depth, and it's recomanded to use `data` funciton for grabbing `data-something` attributes

```js
$(".contact_rows").on("click", ".edit-contact", function () {

var $t = $(this);
var ID = $t.find("span[data-ID]").data('id');

alert(ID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact_rows">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 edit-contact">
          <span data-ID="WANTED ID">SPAN CONTAING DATA ID</span><br>
        <span >GARBAGE DATA</span><br>
        <span>SOMETHING</span>

      </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```